# Get browser generated dragged translucent image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop, html2canvas

I want to get the image that browser generates when we drag an element. Here is the simple example why I want to do this.

[image: Two videos playing inside div]

In the above image the two videos placed inside the black div like picture-in-picture. The black div is able to drag & drop. When I drag the black div the browser generates the **draggable translucent image** like in above picture.

In code implementation I am using `dataTransfer setData & getData` method to access dragged image. When I drop image and use `dataTransfer.getData` gives the dragged div ID and having only black background. I need the actual dragged image to store in `state` in the form of `URL` to use in application. How can I do this without using any external libraries?

I know the `HTML2Canvas` library generates screenshots like browser do. But is there any way to use/store browsers dragged image?

Thank you!

**Edit**: Here is the sample demo of what i want: https://codepen.io/AkshayPatil_/pen/oNoPNQE